# Vue material tabs doesnt switch

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-material

Im trying to use Tabs on vue material to have couple of tabs that will switch in the same page when users click on it.
at the moment the first tabs shows the content but when i lick on the other tabs it just shows empty.

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
  <md-tabs md-sync-route>
      <md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home" to="/home" >
        Home Tab
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab id="tab-pages" md-label="Pages" to="/foo">
        Pages tab
        <p>Unde provident nemo reiciendis officia, possimus repellendus. Facere dignissimos dicta quis rem. Aliquam aspernatur dolor atque nisi id deserunt laudantium quam repellat.</p>
      </md-tab>

    </md-tabs>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TabContent'
}
</script>

<style>
.md-tabs-navigation{
background: linear-gradient(60deg,#ec407a,#d81b60);
}
</style>
```

EDIT : I also added the vue material example https://codesandbox.io/s/48m3qrvmo4?module=App.vue

Comment: You route both tabs to `/foo` deliberately?

Comment: yes i removed one of them to avoid confusion